# Strange internationalization behaviour on iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, internationalization, storyboard

I'm facing a problem and maybe someone knows the solution.
I have an iPhone app that must be in Italian language but currently the project show this settings

http://cl.ly/L57W

Now all screens, when i launch the app is in English.
I don't know what's happened, I started working on this project only now.
Does anyone know if there is a way to reassign all this values in Xcode?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can see in the image 0 files localized. You have to localize. I think all your files are in english by default.